# Import Values and Sort them by there Type

Tags: google-sheets

I have a little trouble with Google Drive sheets / forms.

I need to import the answer from one of our forms into another document. The main problem for me is now, I only need the import if the game is correct.

For better example I put an example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JVtrVRaS3xl15Tnk1Uv9TkOBTUKN9eS1Tv7Mv70oDUI/edit?usp=sharing).

I only know about `=Importrange` but I have no clue how to sort input them.

Would be nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import only the values that meet a criteria in certain order by using Google Sheets built-in functions, first you will have filter and order the values then import them.

You could use `FILTER` and `SORT`, `QUERY` or a **Pivot Table** on a range in the source spreadsheet, then use `IMPORTRANGE` in the destination spreadsheet.